# ASP MVC 3 controller action not receiving all the parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

So I have a view similar to this:

```
...
<input type="text" id="FieldOne" />
<input type="text" id="FieldTwo" />
<input type="text" id="FieldThree" />
...
```

That mimics this class:

```
public class Foo{
    public string FieldOne { get; set; }
    public string FieldTwo { get; set; }
    public string FieldThree { get; set; }
}
```

And an action in the corresponding controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult View(Foo param)
{
   ...
}
```

When I submit the form, the parameter "param" in the Post action properly copies the values of all the fields that match the class, except for one of them (say, FieldOne). These inputs are generated by Html.TextboxFor().

Is this a idiosyncratic problem or is there something I may be forgetting about?

Comment: Could you show us you real view? The problem in your example is that you're not using `name` property

Comment: You can use Fiddler or some other HTTP debugging tool to see what data is being posted when you submit the form.  I agree with Andre that the likely problem, at least in the sample, is that you aren't setting the name on the input elements, only the id.  You can use html help classes in your view instead of writing out the HTML by hand, that that will probably set the name of the inputs.  See:  http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_htmlhelpers.asp

Comment: I am also facing the same problem, when I am trying to passing `input type='textbox' ` values to `controller`, the last parameter is always showing null in the controller.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your input boxes are not valid. They should look as follows:

```
// Start Form
<input type="text" id="FieldOne" name="FieldOne" />
<input type="text" id="FieldTwo" name="FieldTwo" />
<input type="text" id="FieldThree" name="FieldThree" />
// End Form
```

With that said is there any reason why you are not using the Html Helpers? Given your model it would be better to write your form as follows:

```
// Start Form
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FieldOne)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FieldTwo)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FieldThree)
// End Form
```

Comment: OK, it was done with TextBoxFor. I said so in the last sentence of the 3rd-last paragraph. I just found that the reason I was getting no result is because I had _another_ textbox created for that field, so VS couldn't know which one to send back. Nontheless, what you say is true, and since you were the first to answer, and what you say can be helpful, I will give you the points.

Comment: @Heathclif missed your comment regarinding textboxfor. Glad you found the cause.